# Problem when I export my my character to unity

Tags: rigging, export, unity

I started to learn Blender this week to make a game in Unity.

I made this bed that can walk, crouch and jump thanks to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imbIsNAvUpM&t=302s&ab_channel=Polyfjord

[image]

But when I export it to Unity I have that:
[image]

I tried to export it in .fbx and in .blend the result is the same.
And for both I got those messages in the console:

[image]

Can someone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it please?

[image]

Comment: I've never used Unity but a quick Google brought up [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-calculate-tangents-because-mesh-doesnt-contain-normals.747638/) (long) thread in a Unity forum which appears to fix the tangents issue for the poster there. No idea about the other errors though. We'd need to see the Blend file to look for any issues in it. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: If you want to create a game asset in Blender the best if you use only one armature which is the parent of one mesh. You can't use Belnder's curves in Unity, you have to convert it to mesh, thats why they don't have normals. I'm not sure, but the self-intersetting problem may be come from that the armatures are children of a mesh object.

Comment: Thanks @JohnEason , I will try what is in your link, I upload the blend file.

Comment: To add to @FFeller's comment, I don't believe that Blender's modifiers work in Unity either. So anything with a skin modifier on it like the legs won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply scalle to model in blender and everithing will be ok. tap ctrl A and apply scale.
Here you find more information about exporting to unity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UZ-niuRWz8.

Comment: That will not help in this case because it only applies to simple meshes and doesn't address animation problems.